# Determining a MIPS .data int array length at runtime

Tags: arrays, mips, mars-simulator

**Assume:** In MIPS, using MARS, you define an "integer" array in the `.data` section:

```
.data

# Some array of integers
intArray:   .word   1, 2, 3, 4
```

**The problem:** This data can be changed, but the instructions needs to remain the same. This array needs to be parsed through. No "length variable" can be defined.

For example, the array can be changed to be `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`, or `1`, or `1, 2`, etc. Nothing else would change. The `.text` section has to accommodate for variable length arrays *that do not come from user input*.

**Thoughts:** With a char array (string), this would be easy, as they are null-terminated. Simply parse through until you find said character! To the best of my knowledge, however, integer arrays do not have any terminated sequence. It would also be easy if this was read from a user, but this array will be hard-coded. I'm wondering if there is some obscure way (or something that I outright missed) to retrieve how much memory the array holds or was allocated, or if there's some other neat trick for figuring this one out.

I've combed SO and the rest of the internet for this, but it seems that this is an unusual, impractical case so it hasn't been addressed. My apologies if I've missed something. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can use a marker (just like an ASCIIZ string NULL character) if there is an integer you know cannot appear in the array of integers (say for example, -1). The other way to go is split the data in a length field and the actual array (which i think you are prohibited to use when you said "no length variable")

Comment: You can put another label after the array, and that will tell you where the array ends.

Comment: And you can subtract one label from another, which will give you the size of the array as a byte count -- then divide by 4 or shift right by 2 to get item count.  Some assemblers will allow using a formula at assemble time as an immediate in a single instruction, since the result is a runtime constant.  But many assemblers do not have this kind of expression evaluation, so you have to do the subtraction and division/shifting at runtime with a few instructions.

Comment: @RaymondChen that would change the `.text` section though as you have to recompile the source code to take into account the label address

Comment: @gusbro Certainly recompiling the source is in scope, seeing as you also have to recompile to source after changing the `intArray: .word ...` statement.

Comment: OP said he can change data segment but not text segment... Maybe I misunderstood

Comment: @gusbro, the OP states "the instructions must remain the same" -- to me that doesn't necessarily say they have to be unchanged from the original template (not shown by the OP), but once (re)programmed for this exercise, those instructions shouldn't have to change if/when all that changes is the array size/content.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, all, I was testing this. I'm surprised that memory allocation is so reliable in MIPS; it seems obvious enough now, but I suppose being used to higher-level langs made me not even consider subtracting addresses. If someone from here wants to leave a summary of this comment chain, I'll mark it as the answer. Thanks!